# What JSON-RPC / XML-RPC compatbility?

Tags: xml, json, xml-rpc, json-rpc

I'm looking at using JSON-RPC as the webAPI language for a new SOA system.

What I've read is that its faster and simpler than XML-RPC, so sound good.

What I don't get is, do I have to choose? Can't the same data be (automatically) packed and unpacked into XML/JSON/BSON/(whatever else). Can't the language be specified in the HTTP header, and the server do the right thing, by parsing and processing the request?

Are these protocols already compatible?

- "method" means the method name in XML-RPC and JSON-RPC
- "params" means the method parameters ...
- "id" ...

If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

There are some platforms that can switch that stuff for you. I think WCF has this capability. But it largely has to do with what technologies you are using.